# Python concurrent requests and mysql connection pool

Tags: discord.py, mysql-python, mysql-connector

Earlier I was opening and closing a connection for each request but then I got to know about mysql connection pooling which keeps the connections open for us and we can use them whenever required which ultimately saves time and efficiency. Now my question is, max size of a connection pool is 32 so imagine a situation where more than 32 requests are executing concurrently so in that case it'll raise an error. Currently am doing this

**db.py**

```py
from mysql.connector import connect, pooling

pool = None

def init():
  global pool
  pool = pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name='mypool',pool_size=32,pool_reset_session=True,**dbconfig)

def do_work():
  try:
    con = pool.get_connection()
  except:
    con = connect(**dbconfig)
  # execute queries here  
  con.close()
```

It's checking for an available connection in the pool, if all are busy then will open a new one.
So, is this the best approach to achieve this or is there any better alternative?

**Note:** This is in a single threaded application running completely using `asyncio` basically it's a discord bot running on a heavy server

Also what should be an ideal size for a connection pool? **Thanks!**

Comment: Can you create a ConnectionPool class and then make new instances of the respective pool? This would allow you to allocate 'n' amount of connections to specific tasks if need be. Ex: (incoming, outgoing, etc.) However, I am still developing my database 'mental' structure.

If you decide to use a single pool, you can create a method that regulates the number of connections available. (Have the number be an instance variable and then have a method increase/decrease the total allowed connections). This method can check something like (users_total / users_joined_at_some_time_interval)

Comment: Continuation: Get some test data from the system and see if you start noticing hiccups at specific rates. Limiting the connections at 'X' when your design could handle a larger sum might be shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: First of all, I appreciate your reply. I'll respond to your suggestions one by one (what I think about them)
**1.** Create instances of connection pool - AFAIK connection pool always have connections open, so say if I've 3 connection pools with a size of 32 each, I'll have 32*3 i.e 96 connections open which are too much.
**2.** Have a method that regulates connections - How will that help? As I already know that each task needs one connection and by executing `pool.get_connection` if a connection is available I'll get that otherwise it'll raise an error so I can simply handle that error

Comment: **continuing...** I can simply handle that error and open a new connection or add a connection with `pool.add_connection`.
**3.** I tried my above code, and it worked fine when I executed ,more than the allowed limit, requests concurrently, it just took say 32 (size of the pool) connections from the pool and created rest of the connections.
Correct me if am wrong somewhere. Thanks again.